# Adding additional highway values to street_widths dict, not appearing on map

Tags: python, osmnx

Trying to add additional values to highway key in street_widths dict in osmnx.plot.plot_figure_ground but they are not appearing on the map.  Is there a change I need to make somewhere else to add these additional values?

```
street_widths = {
"motorway": 0.75,
"motorway_link": 0.75,
"trunk": 0.5,
"trunk_link": 0.5,
"primary": 0.5,
"primary_link": 0.5,
"secondary": 0.25,
"secondary_link": 0.25,
"tertiary": 0.25,
"tertiary_link": 0.25,
"unclassified": 0.25,
"residential": 0.25,
"living_street": 0.25,
"service": 0.1,
"pedestrian": 0.1,
"track": 0.1,
"footway": 0.1,
"steps": 0.1,
"path": 0.1,
}
```

Map output:

[image: Below is the map output]

Map in OSM using "Query Features". The red line is listed as a residential road:

[image: Below is the map in OSM using "Query Features". The red line is listed as a residential road]

I'm using a slightly modified (colors and output size adjusted) version of the make_plot function from the [examples provided](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.16.0/notebooks/10-building-footprints.ipynb):

UPDATED TEST FUNCTION:

```
import osmnx as ox

ox.settings.log_console=True
ox.settings.use_cache=False

street_widths = {
    "motorway": 0.75,
    "motorway_link": 0.75,
    "trunk": 0.5,
    "trunk_link": 0.5,
    "primary": 0.5,
    "primary_link": 0.5,
    "secondary": 0.25,
    "secondary_link": 0.25,
    "tertiary": 0.25,
    "tertiary_link": 0.25,
    "unclassified": 0.25,
    "residential": 0.25,
    "living_street": 0.25,
    "service": 0.1,
    "pedestrian": 0.1,
    "track": 0.1,
    "footway": 0.1,
    "steps": 0.1,
    "path": 0.1,
    }

land_tags = {
    'building': True
    }

bgcolor="#343434"
edge_color="#FFFFFF"
bldg_color="#FF0000"

place="sd"
point=(32.7362, -117.1129)
dist=8000
dpi=1000

# Helper function to get square street networks, building footprints, and plot them
def make_plot(place, point, dist=dist, dpi=dpi, network_type='all', default_width=0.25,
                street_widths=street_widths):

    # Get bounding box
    bbox = ox.utils_geo.bbox_from_point(point, dist=dist)
    # Get land features using land_tags dictionary
    land = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(center_point=point, tags=land_tags, dist=dist)
    # Plot figure-ground diadram of streets
    fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, network_type=network_type,
                                    default_width=default_width, street_widths=street_widths,
                                    edge_color=edge_color, save=False, show=False, close=True, bgcolor=bgcolor)

    # Plot land footprint
    fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_footprints(land, ax=ax, color=bldg_color, bbox=bbox, dpi=dpi,
                                save=True, show=False, close=True,
                                filepath="{}-dist{}-dpi{}.png".format(place,dist,dpi))

make_plot(place, point, dist)
```

Comment: Please provide a standalone, minimal code snippet for us to reproduce the image you generated for troubleshooting.

Comment: I added a working test function.  It ran to completion in my conda osmnx environment.